# C Preprocessor: Dynamic #Define Creation

Tags: c, dynamic, c-preprocessor

I would like to have the expansion of these **C** preprocessor lines:

```
#define _POUND_ #define
_POUND_ _FALSE 0
_FALSE
```

expand so the last line (i.e. `_FALSE)` expands to 0.  I understand recursive CPP isn't possible directly but that it [can be done](http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic). Unfortunately, I'm not fully sure I follow the logic presented in this link.

I think I need to force an additional evaluation but I don't know how to do that in this case (i.e. I have tried and failed).

Can you help?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to have a macro defining another macro? don't think it is possible..

Comment: You can't define a macro to define another macro, it's just not possible.

Comment: So you want `_POUND` be replaced with `#define`? Mission impossible, dude...

Comment: The feature you want was intentionally left out of the C preprocessor.  It does not look at the results of macro expansion for new directives, and there is no way to change that. (The recursion discussed at your link is a different kind of recursion - it's getting around the rules that are meant to prevent recursive macro *expansion*, not *definition*.)  You may find [M4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4-1.4.17/html_node/index.html#Top) more congenial.

Comment: You can however do: `#ifdef _POUND_ const int _FALSE = 0; #endif`

Comment: Are you asking about this for your own amusement, for the International Obfuscated C Code Contest, or for a project at work? (If it's the last one, I'm glad I don't work at your company, because I wouldn't want to have to maintain your code...)

Comment: No. Show your actual problem, instead of a toy example. There's probably a different way to solve your actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  There is a different way of doing it but it isn't as tidy.  Now it is the only option. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated several times over in comments, what you are looking for is not supported.  Here's what the standard has to say about it:

> A *preprocessing directive* consists of a sequence of preprocessing tokens that satisfies the following constraints: The first token in the sequence is a **#** preprocessing token that (***at the start of translation phase 4***) is either the first character in the source file (optionally after white space containing no new-line characters) or that follows white space containing at least one new-line character.

(C2011, 6.10/2; emphasis added)

Translation phase 4 is the one in which preprocessing directives are executed, so it follows that macro expansion *during* phase 4 cannot cause *bona fide* preprocessing directives to be created.  Macros can be expanded to text that has the form of a preprocessing directive, but such text cannot actually be a directive.

It is true that the text resulting from a macro expansion is re-scanned for more macros to expand, but that process does not involve recognizing preprocessing directives that were not already there.